How to pass key to React functional component inside .map()?
I have faced a typical problem of React must be having 'key prop for each child' inside .map() method.
I have tried to make a key inside a functional component, like...
export default function FunctionalComponent({ title, parentDashedTitle }) {
    const dashedTitle = title.split(' ').join('-');

    return <div
    key={`${dashedTitle}-in-${parentDashedTitle}`}
    >
        {title}
    </div>
}

But it didn't work. I have found that React requires the 'key' prop to be pointed inside the .map() method's function itself, but any time I try to put 'key' prop inside functional component, like...
//Parent.js
export default function ParentComponent({ bigTitle, titles }) {
    const parentDashedTitle = bigTitle.split(' ').join('-');

    return <>
        {
            titles.map(title => {
                const dashedTitle = title.split(' ').join('-');

                return <FunctionalComponent
                key={`${dashedTitle}-in-${parentDashedTitle}`}
                title={title}
                parentDashedTitle={parentDashedTitle}
                />
            })
        }
    </>
}

//Child.js
export default function FunctionalComponent({ title, key }) {
    return <div key={key}>
        {title}
    </div>
}

but it doesn't work either and returns an error of "key is not a prop and will return undefined if it's called". Is there any solution to this problem? Do you have any suggestions?
It doesn't affect work or appearance of my website, but I want this error to be gone. If it helps, I test it in Safari.

You need to add the key prop to just the immediate component you're  returning from your map() method. So you just need return <FunctionalComponent key={\${dashedTitle}-in-${parentDashedTitle}`} ... />and not on your child div (ie: removekeyfromFunctionalComponent`)

https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys: "Note that your components won’t receive key as a prop. It’s only used as a hint by React itself."

you don't need to define the "key" property in your FunctionalComponent, just pass it directly in map as you already do and react will handle the rest, just remove it from declaration function FunctionalComponent({ title }) and dont attach it to div in there, everything else stays as is

One way around this is to use the React Fragment which allows for props like the key and adds no extra element to the DOM. Note that the keys should also be unique.


import { Fragment } from "react";

//Parent.js
export default function ParentComponent({ bigTitle, titles }) {
  const parentDashedTitle = bigTitle.split(" ").join("-");

  return (
      titles.map((title) => {
        const dashedTitle = title.split(" ").join("-");

        return (
          <Fragment key={`${dashedTitle}-in-${parentDashedTitle}`}> //Pass the key here instead
            <FunctionalComponent
              title={title}
            />
          </Fragment>
        );
      })
  );
}


//Child.js
export default function FunctionalComponent({ title }) {
    return <div>
        {title}
    </div>
}




@artemkhi let me know if this works
